# For Each Loop and Select Case - VBA EXCEL

Tags: vba, excel

I need to write value in column based on select case from other 2 columns.

My code is:

```
    Sub VerificaImportoMarcheCU()

Dim Cell As Range
Dim Cell2 As Range
Dim Cell3 As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim DataCambioTabella As String

Sheet3.Activate

LastRow = Sheets("Dati").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
DataCambioTabella = "27/06/2014"

For Each Cell In Sheets(3).Range("C3:C" & LastRow)
    For Each Cell2 In Sheets(3).Range("G3:G" & i)
        For Each Cell3 In Sheets(3).Range("Q3:Q" & LastRow)

    Select Case Cell.Value

    'Imposta Casistiche < 27/06/2014 e Scrivi il valore corretto nella colonna Q foglio Dati
        Case Is < CDate(DataCambioTabella) And Cell2.Value >= 0 And Cell2.Value <= 1100
        Debug.Print (37 + 8)
        Cell3.Value = Sheets(10).Range("E3")
        Case Is < CDate(DataCambioTabella) And Cell2.Value > 1100 And Cell2.Value <= 5200
        Debug.Print (85 + 8)
        Cell3.Value = Sheets(10).Range("E4")
        Case Is < CDate(DataCambioTabella) And Cell2.Value > 5200 And Cell2.Value <= 26000
        Debug.Print (206 + 8)
        Cell3.Value = Sheets(10).Range("E5")
        Case Is < CDate(DataCambioTabella) And Cell2.Value > 26000 And Cell2.Value <= 52000
        Debug.Print (450 + 8)
        Cell3.Value = Sheets(10).Range("E6")
        Case Is < CDate(DataCambioTabella) And Cell2.Value > 52000 And Cell2.Value <= 260000
        Debug.Print (660 + 8)
        Cell3.Value = Sheets(10).Range("E7")
        Case Is < CDate(DataCambioTabella) And Cell2.Value > 260000 And Cell2.Value <= 520000
        Debug.Print (1056 + 8)
        Cell3.Value = Sheets(10).Range("E8")
        Case Is < CDate(DataCambioTabella) And Cell2.Value > 520000
        Debug.Print (1466 + 8)
        Cell3.Value = Sheets(10).Range("E9")
    'Imposta Casistiche > 27/06/2014
        Case Is > CDate(DataCambioTabella) And Cell2.Value >= 0 And Cell2.Value <= 1100
        Debug.Print (43 + 27)
        Cell3.Value = Sheets(10).Range("E15")
        Case Is > CDate(DataCambioTabella) And Cell2.Value > 1100 And Cell2.Value <= 5200
        Debug.Print (98 + 27)
        Cell3.Value = Sheets(10).Range("E16")
        Case Is > CDate(DataCambioTabella) And Cell2.Value > 5200 And Cell2.Value <= 26000
        Debug.Print (237 + 27)
        Cell3.Value = Sheets(10).Range("E17")
        Case Is > CDate(DataCambioTabella) And Cell2.Value > 26000 And Cell2.Value <= 52000
        Debug.Print (518 + 27)
        Cell3.Value = Sheets(10).Range("E18")
        Case Is > CDate(DataCambioTabella) And Cell2.Value > 52000 And Cell2.Value <= 260000
        Debug.Print (759 + 27)
        Cell3.Value = Sheets(10).Range("E19")
        Case Is > CDate(DataCambioTabella) And Cell2.Value > 260000 And Cell2.Value <= 520000
        Debug.Print (1214 + 27)
        Cell3.Value = Sheets(10).Range("E20")
        Case Is > CDate(DataCambioTabella) And Cell2.Value > 520000
        Debug.Print (1686 + 27)
        Cell3.Value = Sheets(10).Range("E21")

End Select
        Next Cell3
    Next Cell2
Next Cell

End Sub
```

My problem is that the loop is not correct because it never comes to cell2 and cell if not before it has cycled for whole cell3.
I need to loop cell, cell2 and cell3 together.

Thank you all for help.
Andrea.

Comment: Do you mean that, for example, if C3 < CDate(DataCambioTabella) And G3 >=0 and G3 <=1100 then `Debug.Print (37 + 8) etc`? If so I think you need only the one loop and use Offset to refer to the G and Q ranges.